# How to use fflib_SObjectSelector class?

Tags: apex, enterprise, inheritance, fflib

I just came across Apex Enterprise Design patterns and this architecture has been really useful. I am trying to implement the selector layer and when I try to extend the `fflib_SObjectSelector` class, I get an error which states `Invalid Type:fflib_SObjectSelector`. I have gone through github library and the trailhead module, and it only mentions that I simply need to extend this class. Yet I am getting this error when trying to do so. Is there anything else that needs to be done in order to use this library? Do we need to create a static resource, download some managed package or is there anything else that I have missed? Any help is really appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: is `fflib` a package namespace?

Answer (score 2):

FFLib is a library which helps you in migrating to Apex Enterprise pattern. You need to deploy all classes in your org (which are dependent as per your need) which are provided in [this library](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/tree/master/fflib/src/classes) then only you can extend and work with this library. It is not implicitly provided by Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

In my org (in addition to what Mr. Frodo states) I have the following (example is for a selector on Order):

```
public virtual class Orders extends ApplicationSelector implements IOrdersSelector {
    public override String getOrderby() {return 'OrderNumber';}
    public List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {    // keep in alpha order
        return new List<Schema.SObjectField> {  
            Order.ID,
            ...
        }
    public static IOrdersSelector newInstance()    {
        return (IOrdersSelector) Application.Selector.newInstance(Order.SObjectType);
    }
    public Schema.SObjectType getSobjectType() {return Order.SObjectType;}

    public virtual Order[] selectById(set<ID> ids) {
        if (ids.isEmpty()) return new List<Order> ();
        fflib_QueryFactory oQF = newQueryFactory()
                                    .setCondition('Id IN :ids');                         
        return Database.query(oQF.toSOQL());    
    }

    ... other custom selector methods ....
}
```

where `ApplicationSelector` is an intermediate class where I can extend some org-specific common behavior to `fflib_SObjectSelector`. Here's an example:

```
public abstract class ApplicationSelector extends fflib_SObjectSelector {
    /**
        Placeholder for org-specific common logic to apply to all Selectors
    **/

    public ApplicationSelector() {
        super();
    }
    public ApplicationSelector(Boolean includeFieldSets, Boolean enforceCRUD, Boolean enforceFLS, Boolean sortFields) {
        super(includeFieldSets,enforceCRUD,enforceFLS,sortFields);
    }

    abstract Schema.SObjectType getSObjectType();

    /**
    *   getFieldSetFieldsAsSOQL - returns fields in a fieldset for use in dynamic SOQL. Normally, one would use
    *                               fflib_QueryFactory.selectFieldSet in the specification of the queryFactory 
    *                               but in certain use cases where the SOQL must be constructed manually (e.g. to include FOR UPDATE)
    *                               we need a way around this. The alternative is to enhance fflib_QueryFactory but that
    *                               locks us out of future changes from the Open Source Community
    **/
    protected String getFieldSetFieldsAsSOQL(Schema.Fieldset fieldset) {
        if (fieldSet == null) return '';
        String[] fieldNames = new List<String>();
        for (Schema.FieldSetMember field: fieldSet.getFields())
            fieldNames.add(field.getFieldPath());
        return String.join(fieldNames,','); 
    }
}
```